# Kernel crashes on invoking Python prompt

Tags: kernel, python

Apologies if this is a naive question. A typing error keeps crashing the kernel.
My typing error is to start a line with ">",  unintentionally invoking Python. The problem is that this crashes the kernel.
Is this a bug? Is there any way to disable the invocation of Python so that my clumsy typing doesn't lead to crashes? I'm running Mathematica 12.2.0.0 on Mac OSX Mojave (10.14.6).

Comment: Where are you typing ">" that it invokes python?  Are you running Mma via the command line?  In a notebook?  In no environment should simply starting a line with > invoke python.

Comment: @evanb This was added a while back. "Use > at the beginning of a line to start an external code cell evaluated with ExternalEvaluate:" in the docs [ExternalEvaluate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html).

Comment: VERY interesting!  I will have to check it out!

Comment: evanb, in a notebook. I intended to start the line with ?procname to remind myself of the ordering of the arguments to procname. I'm a poor typist and sometimes hit > instead of ?. When I do, Mathematica invokes the python prompt and the kernel seems to be wiped clean. All definitions are lost. Big penalty for a small typing error. Thanks